# What is the meaning of "April smile?"

Tags: phrases, expressions, phrase-meaning

I was reading *Rebecca of Sunnybrook Farm*, and I came across the phrase "April smile." I was unable to find a meaning of this phrase using Google, so I thought I'd ask here.

Here is a quote where the phrase is found:

> "Give me some more examples of the subjunctive, Rebecca, and that will do for this afternoon," she said.
>
> "If I had not loved mackerel I should not have been thirsty;" said Rebecca with an **April smile**, as she closed her grammar. "If thou hadst loved me truly thou wouldst not have stood me up in the corner. If Samuel had not loved wickedness he would not have followed me to the water pail."

— *from* Rebecca of Sunnybrook Farm *by Kate Douglas Wiggin, 1903 edition, pages 61-62.*

What exactly does the author mean by "April smile" in this context? And how does it differ from a regular smile — eg. *said Rebecca with a smle, as she closed her grammar.* —?

Comment: [A smile that comes after great distress, like sunshine after a storm](http://www.rc.umd.edu/editions/southey_letters/Part_Four/HTML/letterEEd.26.2449.html#3).

Comment: Another literary citation to add to OP's:  A Birthday Present
Say what, to please you, you would have me be.'' 
Then listen, dear! 
I fain would have you very fair to see, 
And sweet to hear. 

`You should have Aphrodite's form and face, 
With Dian's tread; 
And something of Minerva's lofty grace 
Should crown your head. 

. . . .

Comment: `Summer should wander in your voice, and Spring 
Gleam in your gaze, 
And pure thoughts ripen in your heart that bring 
Calm Autumn days. 

`Yours should be winning ways that make Love live, 
And ne'er grow old, 
With ever something yet more sweet to give, 
Which you withhold. 

`You should have generous hopes that can beguile 
Life's doubts and fears, 
And, ever waiting on your April smile, 
The gift of tears. 

`You should be close to us as earth and sea, 
And yet as far 
As Heaven itself. In sooth, I'd have you be 
Just what you are.'

Alfred Austin

Comment: @MichaelOwenSartin and Laure please post your comments as answers. They are both right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: done so, but I don't usually like to give as an answer what one can easily find on the web since I'm not convinced it's what StackExchange is all about.

Comment: @Laure but if there are no "answers" the question is left open. I don't think it the OP's question is classifiable as *general reference*, although its meaning can be easily guessed at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Romantic poet [Robert Southey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Southey) used the phrase [in one of his letters](http://www.rc.umd.edu/editions/southey_letters/Part_Four/HTML/letterEEd.26.2449.html), as a postscript to a somewhat melancholy letter he writes :

> A momentary recollection has just brought an April smile upon my cheek,...

The editor gives that definition of the phrase in a footnote:

> A smile that comes after great distress, like sunshine after a storm